# XCode crash on load after Big Sur installation

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I use React Native for my dayjob, which was working fine until I did my first restart after downloading Big Sur. Now XCode crashes on load, and running `yarn run ios` only launches the Simulator and the app fails to compile. When I open XCode, it looks like this every time.

[image]

I have tried:

- uninstalling and reinstalling XCode.
- deleting Derived Data.
- deleting the Workspace file and `pod installing` to regenerate it.
- deleting the xcuserdata file.

Is there anything else I can do before I have to bite the bullet and spend ages downgrading back to Catalina?

Comment: have the same issue after upgrading to big sur. how you've solved this?

Comment: Hey @nastassia. The issue for me wound up being to do with iCloud. I turned it off and the problem went away. It's a pain, and I haven't found a way to use both at once yet, but it helped! Good luck.

Comment: thanks a lot for answering me! I've moved project from iCloud and it works finally! omg I've spent 2 days trying to fix it

Comment: I'm so glad I could help! This problem stole two days of my life so if anyone can benefit from my pain I'm happy :) Good luck to you!